# Javascript - Better solution for finding anagrams - Time complexity O (n log n)

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, anagram

**DISCLAIMER**

Hey everyone, I understand that there are few Javascript questions/answers that deal with figuring out the how to find if two words are anagrams.

I'm not just looking for a function that figures out whether two words/strings are anagrams. I'm looking for a function that will be quicker than the one provided below. Currently, I believe the time complexity of the function below is **O (n log n)**.

I'd like to figure out a function that has a time complexity of **O(n)** or something that has a runtime that is quicker than the one provided.

**CODE**

```
const isAnagram = (str1, str2) => {

  str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
  str2 = str2.toLowerCase();


  if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
     return false
  }

  let sortStr1 = str1.split('').sort().join('').trim();
  let sortStr2 = str2.split('').sort().join('').trim();

  return sortStr1 === sortStr2
 };

console.log(isAnagram('dog', 'goD')); //true
```

Comment: use `O(n)` sort and your code is `O(n)`. what you've tried by the way :/

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean by that

Comment: something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort does gives you `O(n)` sort complexity.

Comment: so are you saying my method does return a time complexity of O(n)?

Comment: yes if you use `O(n)` sorting method.

Comment: ah ic, what the answer below is showing then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try counting based algorithm.

```js
const isAnagram = (str1, str2) => {

  str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
  str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
  //and remove any char you think not important (like space) here
  
  if (str1.length !== str2.length) return false
  
  let counting = {}
  for(let c of str1) 
     if(counting[c]) ++counting[c]
     else counting[c] = 1
  
  for(let c of str2)
     if(counting[c]) --counting[c]
     else return false
  
  return true
};

console.log(isAnagram('dog', 'goD')); //true
console.log(isAnagram('eleven plus two', 'twelve plus one')); //true
console.log(isAnagram('dog', 'hot')); //false
console.log(isAnagram('banana', 'nana')); //false
```

Comment: I believe this will give us a time complexity of O(n^2)?

Comment: @mph85 why? where you get it from?

Comment: no my mistake, i was thinking it was nested, but it's not

Comment: what is going on in the if statements? `if(counting[c]) --counting[c]` What does this mean? and the following `else counting[c] = 1`?

Comment: @mph85 first `if(counting[c])` means `if(c in counting)`, second `if(counting[c])` means `if(c in counting && c != 0)`

Comment: `counting[c] = 1` just set the member to 1 (since this member have not been exist).

Comment: @mph85 `if(counting[c])` checks if the letter in second string is present in  first. If it is then subtract the count. The idea is that if count becomes `0` in obj and letter is still present in `str2` then return false.   The second `else counting[c] = 1` means during the if during the iteration of first `str1`(which is to fill the object) if certain letter is not included in object yet(means its count is `0`) then initialize its count to `1`

Comment: @appleapple `if(counting[c]) ++counting[c]
     else counting[c] = 1` can be `counting[c] = counting[c] + 1 || 1`

Comment: @MaheerAli `undefined+1 || 1` cool method! I never think about that!  But I think the symmetric of 2 loop looks good :)

Comment: hmm, i think i understand, ill have to mull over that a little more, either way, i appreciate the explanations

Comment: @mph85 fix some error (check 2 string have same length), please check again

Comment: sorry what am i looking for?

Comment: @appleapple sorry, i still don't know what i need to fix, what's wrong with that if statement? Isn't it just saying that if the two strings aren't equal to each other, that we can automatically eliminate them?

Comment: @appleapple are you saying that I don't need the brackets?

Comment: @mph85 sorry for confusing, I'm saying **I** forgot to add the length comparison and it would wrong for last example, so I fix **my** code. the code is now **correct**.

Comment: @appleapple ahh, sorry for the confusion. I misunderstood. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible idea that comes from: [An Algorithm for Finding Anagrams](https://skerritt.blog/an-algorithm-for-finding-anagrams/) and is based on the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) that states:

> Every integer greater than `1` either is a prime number itself or can be represented as the product of prime numbers and that, moreover, this representation is unique, up to (except for) the order of the factors.

So, if we assign each letter in the alphabet to a prime number, and then compute the product of these numbers, this number will be unique ( because of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic). That means that for a multiset of letters, the product of prime numbers for each letter in that multiset is unique. Then, if two words or sentences have the same number, these two words or sentences are anagrams of each other.

## Implementation:

```js
let letters = {"a":2, "b":3, "c":5, "d":7, "e":11, "f":13, "g":17, "h":19, "i":23, "j":29, "k":31, "l":37, "m":41, "n":43, "o":47, "p":53, "q":59, "r":61, "s":67, "t":71, "u":73, "v":79, "w":83, "x":89, "y":97, "z":101};

const isAnagram = (str1, str2) =>
{
    str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    str2 = str2.toLowerCase();            
    let repStr1 = 1, repStr2 = 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(str1.length, str2.length); i++)
    {
        repStr1 *= (str1[i] && letters[str1[i]]) ? letters[str1[i]] : 1;
        repStr2 *= (str2[i] && letters[str2[i]]) ? letters[str2[i]] : 1;
    }

    return (repStr1 === repStr2);
};

console.log("[dog, goD] Anagrams?", isAnagram('dog', 'goD'));
console.log("[dogo, goD] Anagrams?", isAnagram('dogo', 'goD')); 
console.log("[Roast Beef, Eat for BSE] Anagrams?", isAnagram('Roast Beef', 'Eat for BSE'));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

**Advantages**

- Accepts anagrams of different lengths (check third example).
- Is `O(n)` (only one loop is required).

**Disadvantages**

- Won't work for large expressions, there will be an overflow on the generated number.
- Needs a predefined dictionary between letters and primer numbers.
- Won't work for expression that contains rare characters, unless you extend the dictionary, but the overflow will become more frequently.

Comment: I think this is palindromic, not anagram?